# Setting up GIT on Mac OS to work with Google Code

Tags: macos, git, google-code

When I try to push the repository from a MacOS Shell I get this error

fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your generated googlecode.com password; see https://code.google.com/hosting/settings

How should I provide it with the right password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should pick up your credentials in your `~/.netrc` file, which should include:

```
machine code.google.com 
login your_CodeGoogleCom_Login 
password your_CodeGoogle_password
```

(and `chmod go= ~/.netrc`)

Make sure to do:

```
git config --global user.name "google.username"
git config --global user.email "google.username@gmail.com"
git remote set-url origin https://code.google.com/p/projectname
```

(avoid using an url like `https://google.username@code.google.com/p/projectname` when you are using a `.netrc` file for credentials)

Comment: i did this but it actually seems to be ignored by git

Comment: @lowcoupling what does `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: @lowcoupling so if it is an http url, with `code.google.com` in it, it should take the `~/.netrc` into account.

Comment: @lowcoupling is your url like: `https://username@code.google.com/...`? Because if it is, you might try as `https://code.google.com/...`. See my edited answer.

Comment: It worked I think it was because of the username in the url. Thank you!